# WSO2 EI 6.4 and error Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Using `WSO2 EI 6.4.0` to send a SOAP message with `wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SigOnly"` works fine when the HTTP response code is 200. The signature is well checked and message flow can continue.

When the response is a SOAP fault with the response code 500, the initiating request sent to EI keeps hanging.  The Send mediator doesn't receive any exception so I cannot handle it (what I would like to report it to the caller) in the sequence flow, even in a faultSequence. I just get this error in my logs: `Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid.`

I really don't understand why - in this fault situation - the signature or decryption could be invalid while it is valid with non faulty SOAP responses.  I don't see differences between the soap headers structure (fault vs. non-fault), it seems to me only the body is different:

```
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1-2b51dae55e169f7625472a2369df8671" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Message bcd45e75-b778-4fe1-83fb-ea97e4015sss failed : VALI-0100 - Validation of request message failed : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'Q1andQ2' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[Q1, Q2, Q1+Q2, SO]'. It must be a value from the enumeration., org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Q1andQ2' of element 'v21:codeQ' is not valid. 
    </faultstring>
    <faultactor>
    ...
```

And the full exception:

```
[2021-02-09 17:37:01,216] [EI-Core] ERROR - AxisEngine The signature or decryption was invalid org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
 at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:194)
 at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:96)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:263)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
 at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:703)
 at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:124)
 at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:332)
 at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
 at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:221)
 at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:93) 
 ... 9 more 

[2021-02-09 17:37:01,220] [EI-Core] ERROR - ClientWorker Fault processing response message through Axis2 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
 at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:194)
 at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:96)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
 at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:263)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid
```

Any help should be appreciated to tell me what am I to do to be able to get the fault reported up to the mediator level so I could manage the flow.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be a bug in WSO2 EI 6.4.0. Please refer to issue [#4155](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4155) for more details